# Using IDisposable interface to displose composition of classes

Tags: c#, idisposable

I have implemented `IDisposable` Interface and in below code for class `A`.

Should I dispose objects of class `B` either?

```
        public class A : IDisposable
        {
            private B _objB = null;

            public A()
            {
                _objB = new B();
            }

            public void Load(string fileName, int loadFlags)
            {
                _objB .Load(fileName, 0);
            }
            public void Close()
            {
                _objB .Reset();
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }
        }
```

In the void `Dispose()` method I dispose class `A` from `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)`;

In class `A` i declare class `B` so it need to dispose using the same `C.SuppressFinalize(_objB);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You thoroughly misunderstand what GC.SuppressFinalize() does.  It only matters when your class has a destructor (aka finalizer).  You don't, so don't call it.  If B in fact implements IDisposible then just dispose it:

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _objB.Dispose();
    }
```

With the assumption that _objB can be safely disposed more than once and that using it after it is disposed already generates ObjectDisposedException.